# Build a column from value of another column in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a table as below.

```
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------------+
|cust_pr_id|cust_pr_name         |now_prcs_status  |pr_join_dt|installation_due          |installation_completed    |seg_purchase_due |seg_purchase_completed |wire_in_line_due  |wire_in_line_completed  |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------------+
|9822647220|Jonathan RM Berlin   |installation     |20200202  |2019-07-11 08:00:00.000000|2019-07-10 12:20:30.132000|1562745600000    |1562761216526          |                  |                        |
|7166582305|Paola RM Berlin      |seg purchase     |20200903  |2019-07-11 08:00:00.000000|2019-07-10 12:20:30.132000|1562745600000    |1562761216526          |                  |                        |
|9964201263|Roy RM Poland        |installation     |20201023  |2019-07-11 08:00:00.000000|2019-07-10 12:20:30.132000|1562745600000    |1562761216526          |                  |                        |
|7288402221|Katerina RM Mia      |wire in line     |20201110  |2019-07-11 08:00:00.000000|2019-07-10 12:20:30.132000|1562745600000    |1562761216526          |                  |                        |
|8424182826|Smidge RM Siberia    |seg purchase     |20200902  |2019-07-15 08:00:00.000000|2019-07-10 09:11:30.599000|                 |                       |                  |                        |
|4445859610|Donna RM Brazil      |seg purchase     |20200903  |2019-07-15 08:00:00.000000|2019-07-10 09:11:30.599000|                 |                       |                  |                        |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+------------------+------------------------+
```

From this data I want to build a dataset as below.
Here, if the value of the field "now_prcs_status" is "installation" then I need to produce value of "installation_due" as "curr_prcs_due" and value of "installation_completed" as "curr_prcs_completed".
Similarly, if the value of "now_prcs_status" is "seg purchase", I need to produce value of "seg_purchase_due" as "curr_prcs_due" and value of "seg_purchase_completed" as "curr_prcs_completed".
Same when the value of "cust_pr_name" is "wire in line" I need to populate its due and completed values as "curr_prcs_due" and "seg_purchase_completed" respectively.

```
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|cust_pr_id|cust_pr_name         |now_prcs_status  |pr_join_dt|curr_prcs_due             |curr_prcs_completed       |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|9822647220|Jonathan RM Berlin   |installation     |20200202  |2019-07-11 08:00:00.000000|2019-07-10 12:20:30.132000|
|7166582305|Paola RM Berlin      |seg purchase     |20200903  |1562745600000             |1562761216526             |
|9964201263|Roy RM Poland        |installation     |20201023  |2019-07-11 08:00:00.000000|2019-07-10 12:20:30.132000|
|7288402221|Katerina RM Mia      |wire in line     |20201110  |                          |                          |
|8424182826|Smidge RM Siberia    |seg purchase     |20200902  |                          |                          |
|4445859610|Donna RM Brazil      |seg purchase     |20200903  |                          |                          |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

The above is the expected value.

**I donot want to go with a sql case statement as I have total 105 distinct values for cust_pr_name in my actual dataset and I don't want to end up writing 105 case statements.**

Can someone help me with the approach to achieve this through pyspark or hive..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some list comprehension should do the job:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

prcs = [c[:-4] for c in df.columns[4::2]]

df2 = df.select(
    *df.columns[:4], 
    F.coalesce(*[
        F.when(
            F.col('now_prcs_status') == p.replace('_', ' '), 
            F.col(p + '_due')
        ) 
        for p in prcs
    ]).alias('curr_prcs_due'), 
    F.coalesce(*[
        F.when(
            F.col('now_prcs_status') == p.replace('_', ' '), 
            F.col(p + '_completed')
        ) 
        for p in prcs
    ]).alias('curr_prcs_completed')
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+----------+------------------+---------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|cust_pr_id|cust_pr_name      |now_prcs_status|pr_join_dt|curr_prcs_due             |curr_prcs_completed       |
+----------+------------------+---------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|9822647220|Jonathan RM Berlin|installation   |20200202  |2019-07-11 08:00:00.000000|2019-07-10 12:20:30.132000|
|7166582305|Paola RM Berlin   |seg purchase   |20200903  |1562745600000             |1562761216526             |
|9964201263|Roy RM Poland     |installation   |20201023  |2019-07-11 08:00:00.000000|2019-07-10 12:20:30.132000|
|7288402221|Katerina RM Mia   |wire in line   |20201110  |null                      |null                      |
|8424182826|Smidge RM Siberia |seg purchase   |20200902  |null                      |null                      |
|4445859610|Donna RM Brazil   |seg purchase   |20200903  |null                      |null                      |
+----------+------------------+---------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```